# I got promoted while I am on a job hunt. Will it be wise to mention about getting promoted during an interview?

Tags: interviewing, promotion

I am on a jobhunt and my 1st interview with Company B went well. To my surprise, the next day, in my current job, I got promoted. I still want to look for a new company and Company B has contacted me for a 2nd interview. And this interview will be with the Senior Manager (1st interview was with  the Asst. Manager). Will it be okay to mention about getting promoted in current company? Can I use this promotion as one of my selling-point?

Comment: Which kind of position did you apply for, and which kind of promotion did you receive?

Comment: Did the promotion change your job duties in any way, or is it just a pay bump?

Comment: I applied for Product Quality Engineer aand they mentioned that interview result can also lead to Assistant Product Quality engineer. I used to be assistant product engineer and the duties i am doing are duties of a product engineer. Begininng  this year, some of my manager's duties were past down to me as well. Then just last week, they promoted me to Product Engineer.

Comment: I just want to make sure I understand. You applied for a Product Quality Engineer, but based on the interview results, you could possible receive an offer for either an Assistant Product Quality Engineer or a Product Quality Engineer position. Is the Assistant Product Quality Engineer a level below the Product Quality Engineer position (it seems that way from the title, but I'd like to confirm).

Comment: Yes that is correct. @thomasowens

Answer (score 6):

At a minimum, update your LinkedIn profile to reflect your new job title and role.

I don't know enough about your situation to offer solid advice on discussing your promotion with your prospective employer.

Comment: I applied for Product Quality Engineer aand they mentioned that interview result can also lead to Assistant Product Quality engineer. I used to be assistant product engineer and the duties i am doing are duties of a product engineer. Begininng  this year, some of my manager's duties were past down to me as well. Then just last week, they promoted me to Product Engineer. Before i was doing 2 people's job. Now i am doing 4 people's job

Answer (score 6):

My advice would be to continue on with the interviews, without bringing it up explicitly. I would recommend updating any resumes that you submit to other companies as well as any online profiles (such as LinkedIn) that you have. At this time, you don't need to give the company you are interviewing with any updates or changes, since you're in the middle of the interview process.

If Company B comes back to you with an offer, then you can decide what to do. If the offer is worth it, you can accept and give your notice at your current employer. However, if Company B's offer is insufficient, you can negotiate. One point of negotiation may be not accepting a job title that would be a step backwards or a salary that is less than what you are making now.

Without knowing the details of your situation, I can't say that I wouldn't accept a lower salary or a lower title. If you are in a toxic environment, it may be worth it for your career or your health to accept a lower salary (although do make sure you aren't putting yourself in a financially dangerous position). Titles also vary by company - I went from a Senior Software Engineer to a Software Engineer position because I went from a company with 6 different titles to one with 2 - so you may be able to accept or justify a title change.

When it comes time to accept, reject, or negotiate the offer, do so on the merits of the position and what it offers you. Don't get too hung up on the current salary (as long as it is sufficient to meet your needs) or title if it is something that is better for you (especially in the long term).

Comment: thanks for the advice. Would there be a need to update the resume i gave hr for company b? And if my second interviewer ask what is my current position, it will be alright to state Product Engineer, yes?

Comment: @TxRx I'd say that you wouldn't need to update HR with a resume, at least in the US. However, if they ask for one again or ask you to fill out any other documents, I'd make sure that it is accurate. And if someone asks what your title is, you should tell them your accurate job title. There's just no need to make a deal out of the fact that you got a promotion or a title change. It really doesn't change anything at this point.

Answer (score 2):

When a company is about to make a job offer to a new employee they have a concern about a counter offer. They try to determine why the person is looking for a new job, and if they are likely to reject the offer when their current company makes the counter offer.

While it is good that you are continuing to look after receiving the promotion, there is still no guarantee that you will take an offer from the new company. In fact the promotion may have lowered the delta between the old company and the new company.

Telling them about the promotion is likely to make them worried. They now know that you have received a counter offer. They may be worried that the promotion may make it harder to leave. They will be concerned that their second choice will take another job, while you wait the maximum number of days before rejecting them.

Telling them won't be a selling point because they may believe that the promotion is only because the current company was worried you are about to leave. It doesn't tell them about the qualities you have, only that your current company wants to keep you around a little longer because it is an inconvenient time for you to leave.

The general advice is to reject a counteroffer. The general advice is also to not use the counteroffer as a bargaining chip with the new company, because you might lose both jobs. Telling them about the promotion before an offer is even made increases the risk there will be no offer.

Comment: In the question, it doesn't appear that the current employer knows that he is looking for a new position. How can this be seen as a counteroffer? A counteroffer only comes around the time you give notice and let the company know you have another offer, not when they don't even know you are looking. The last three paragraphs about a counteroffer don't appear relevant at all to the question.

Comment: If you tell the new company about the promotion, then they are likely to view it as a counteroffer. I know I would. I would be concerned that the motivation has changed, and it would just be expedient to drop them from consideration.

Comment: @thomasowens yes. The current company does not know i am looking for a job.

Comment: @TxRx - Mhorna's advice is not to tell the company you interviewed for in the event you get an offer.